# column index of datagridview present in child form changes when child form is opened from an Mdi Form

Tags: c#

I am having an MdiParent form and i am opening a child from it by this code :

```
private void editCategoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    formHide();
    EditCatagoryGrid objEditCategoryGrid = new EditCatagoryGrid();        
    objEditCategoryGrid.MdiParent = this;
    objEditCategoryGrid.Location = new Point(100, 80);
    objEditCategoryGrid.Show();        
}

public void formHide()
{      
    Form[] form = this.MdiChildren;
    foreach (Form f in form)
    {
        f.Hide();
        //ChangeMdiColor();
    }
}
```

There is a `datagridview` present in `EditCatagoryGrid`. When I open `EditCatagoryGrid` form without using mdiform it works fine, but when using the mdiparent form the column index of datagridview present in the `EditCatagoryGrid` changes, it doesn't work. I have not been able to figure out this problem. Can any one please help?

@Desolate thanks for giving the response, My code to bind the datagridview is as follow:

```
    private void EditCatagoryGrid_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        bindDataGridView();
        addCategoryComboBoxToDataGridView();

        //closeAllOtherForms();
    }
    public void bindDataGridView()
    {
        objCon = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source= E:\Showroom software\Showroom software\SalePurchase.sdf ;Persist Security Info=False;");
        objCon.Open();
        objDa = new SqlCeDataAdapter("select CategoryId   from Category", objCon);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        objDa.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        objCon.Close();

    }

    public void addCategoryComboBoxToDataGridView()
    {
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Category);

        Category.Name = "cmbcatagory";
        Category.HeaderText = "Category";
        Category.Width = 150;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 100;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code related to the dataGridView that exists in EditCategoryGrid form. There is the bottlekneck. The given code is meaningless.

Comment: i have edited my post to give details of how i binded the datagridview

Comment: How many columns dataGridView have before calling `addCategoryComboBoxToDataGridView()` ?

Comment: before calling addCategoryComboBoxToDataGridView() gridview has one column that is CategoryID

Comment: See the answer I put.

Comment: thanks @Desolate for giving ur precious time to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the problem solved , Functions that are called onload event of EditCatagoryGrid form has to be called onshow event of EditCatagoryGrid form and remove them from onload event of EditCatagoryGrid form

```
private void EditCatagoryGrid_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindDataGridView();
    addCategoryComboBoxToDataGridView();   
}
```

Comment: can any one please tell why is it not working properly when it is called onload event of  EditCatagoryGrid Form ?

Comment: How would we know? Absolutely we cannot guess. We must view your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is difficult to be answered while not knowing enough information about your code. Thus no one can guess the problem specifically.

Best advice of me is to, debug your code. Put a breakpoint on `Load` and `Change` events and in every critical method in `CategoryEditForm` and see what is going on.

Possible problem: Some exception like `NullReferenceException`, `OutOfRangeException`, or `SqlException` is being thrown, and the UI does not report the exception.